# Is it possible to know the progress of a transaction.commit operation?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I'm using JPA in my application to bundle a series of insert and updates into one commit() operation.

While that commit is running, is it possible to learn the progress of that operation (0-100%) so I can display that in a progress bar to the user?

I could split my updates into many commits, but that would make the entire job take longer.

Using EclipseLink as my JPA provider.

Comment: Which Jpa implementation are you using? Hibernate?

Comment: Please post your simplified code. A `commit` is typically a very quick operation even for large transactions and need not be *progress bared*.

Comment: @Marmite It's a file import with a few thousand records that ends up running multiple inserts and updates per each record.

Comment: EclipseLink also has performance monitoring tooling (see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/monitoring003.htm ) that you might use. Unfortunately though, I don't think either option is exactly what you want - they both seemed aimed at tracking stats, and don't seem to gauge what is left in a transaction. For that, you would need to hook into EclipseLink's session listeners https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_session_event_listener.htm . This might allow getting the changeset it is using, and help track how much has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to create something like that would be to use the `org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsImpl` class of `hibernate`. You can programmatically get different metrics from the instantiation of this class. Hibernate statistics generation must be enabled for this to work. You can enable it by setting the property `hibernate.generate_statistics` to `true`.

The statistics instance has a method called `getQueryExecutionCount()` that you might be able to use to build a progress bar. It gives the number of queries that were executed by the current JPA EntityManagerFactory or Hibernate. If you keep calling that method in a `while` loop while the queries are still running you might be able to show the percentage of completed queries by dividing the return value of `getQueryExecutionCount()` by the total amount of queries that need to be processed. [Heres a good tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statistics/) that explains all the different metrics that are available.

I must also point out that turning on hibernate statistics could slow your application down. So if you want to use this feature in production then you must also test whether this slowdown is acceptable or not.

EDIT: You could also choose to only turn hibernate statistics on right before the queries will run and turn it off after they've completed.

The `StatisticsImpl` class has a method called `setStatisticsEnabled(boolean b)` that you can use to programmatically turn it on or off.

EDIT 2: I'm assuming here that you are using `Hibernate` as the JPA provider. If not i'll remove this answer.

Comment: I'm using eclipselink. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Holden i'm not familiar with eclipselink